# Hiding button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML file, there are 3 buttons as save,edit and cancel. Im hiding save and edit button depends on the functionality in javascript.

```
<div class="controls col-sm-9">
    <button onclick="modJs.save();return false;" class="saveBtn btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <t>Save</t></button>
    <button onclick="modJs.editrecord();return false;" class="EditBtn btn btn-primary " style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <t>Update</t></button>
    <button onclick="modJs.cancel();return false;" class="cancelBtn btn pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <t>Cancel</t></button>
</div>
```

in my javascript fucntion, im showing and hiding edit and save buttons.

```
if(object != undefined && object != null) {   //editing selected
    $(".editBtn").show();
    $(".saveBtn").hide();
    this.fillForm(object);
}
```

Already i gave `display:none` in html tag for edit button. I want to show edit button if object is not null (that means edit). By the above code, the save button get hide, but edit button is not showing.

Comment: Its a typo .... your class is EditBtn  and you are calling as editBtn

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there is a little spelling mistake there

replace

```
$(".editBtn").show();
```

with

```
 $(".EditBtn").show();
```

Or maybe simply change classname `EditBtn` to `editBtn` to keep naming consistent.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML you're using the class `EditBtn`, in the JS code you use the class `editBtn`. Class names are case sensitive! Change it in the HTML to `editBtn`.